# Convert Array list to Sparse Array

Tags: android, arrays, sparse-matrix

I have copied some code from a project and want to reuse a small part of it in my private app.

The class contains a Sparse Array

```
public class GolfResult {

    String hcpAfter;
    String hcpBefore;
    SparseArray roundResults;

    public GolfResult() {
        hcpAfter = "";
        hcpBefore = "";
        roundResults = new SparseArray();
    }
}
```

I have created an `ArrayList` for `roundResults` that is filled with the necessary data.

Then I am trying to fill the instance with content.

```
GolfResult golferRes = new GolfResult();
SparseArray<RoundResults> hu= new SparseArray<>();
hu = roundresults; // *
golferRes.setHcpAfter("33");
golferRes.setHcpBefore("kk");
golferRes.setRoundResults(hu);
```

But the problem is that `hu = roudresults` is not possible, because of the error message:

> required: Android.util.SparseArray found: java.util.Array List

Any help will be welcome.

After receiving two helpful answers I got a step further, but now I am facing the problem that my SparseArray hu  is empty {}.

The content of hu should be the class roundresults that has the following structure:

```
public class RoundResults {
boolean actualRound;
private List<HoleResult> holeResults;
Integer roundId;
Integer roundNumber;
String unfinishedReason;
```

The arrayList roundresults has the size of 1 and has data in the objects.

```
unfinishedReason =""
holeResults = ArrayLIST size= 18
roundID = "1"
roundNumber = "1"
actualRound = true
```

hu ={}

```
mValues = All elements are null
mSize = 0
```

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: You should consider validating the answer that helped you out.

Comment: SparseArrays are equivalent of HashMaps not ArrayLists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, maybe you can try with this:

```
for ( int i=0; i<roundresults.size(); i++ ) {
    hu.put(i,roundresults.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SparseArray is different than ArrayList, from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html):

> **SparseArrays** map integers to Objects. Unlike a normal array of
>   Objects, *there can be gaps in the indices*. It is intended to be more
>   memory efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Objects, both
>   because it avoids auto-boxing keys and its data structure doesn't rely
>   on an extra entry object for each mapping.

It's using a key value pair principle where the key is an integer and the value which the key mapping is the object. You need to use put [(int key, E value)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#put(int, E)) where the E is your object. Remember that:

> Adds a mapping from the specified key to the specified value,
>   **replacing** the previous mapping from the **specified key** if there was
>   one.

So you need to use a loop to add each object in your ArrayList as @valentino-s says:

```
SparseArray<RoundResults> hu= new SparseArray<>();
for( int i = 0; i < roundresults.size(); i++) {
  // i as the key for the object.
  hu.put(i, roundresults.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, now I could avoid the error message but SparseArray hu = {}, although roundresults.get(0) is filled and has the following class structure: public class RoundResults {
    boolean actualRound;
    private List<HoleResult> holeResults;
    Integer roundId;
    Integer roundNumber;
    String unfinishedReason;

Comment: I couldn't grasp the meaning of your comment. Could you please elaborate it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to set the initial capacity of the SparseArray if you create a new one right before the loop to fill it?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found a solution for the empty hu:

Instead of put I used append and it is working now.

```
hu.append(i, roundresults.get(i));
```

Time for a beer.

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you use append() or put(). You probably changed something else, too.